# How to create products in MORYX when importing orders from external systems?

Tags: c#, moryx

I'm fetching order data from an external MES system and try to create
orders in MORYX accordingly.

This is, roughly, what creating the order looks like:

```
var orderContext = new OrderCreationContext
{
    Number = externalOrder.Number,
};


var operationContext = new OperationCreationContext
{
    Order = orderContext,
    TotalAmount = externalOrder.Amount,
    Number = externalOrder.OperationNumber,
    ProductIdentifier = externalOrder.ProductNumber,
};
orderContext.Operations.Add(operationContext);

_orderManagement.AddOperation(operationContext);
```

It successfully creates an order, but if the provided product doesn't exist yet
in MORYX, it comes with an error:

> It was not possible to assign the product!

In this case, I'd like to create the product on the fly, but my first guess, the
*ProductManager*, doesn't seem to provide a method to do this.

If it is, how is it possible to import *yet unknown* products into MORYX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already hints you towards the solution. By default MORYX uses the given identifier and tries to fetch a digitial twin from `IProductManagement`. But you can customize that behavior by implementing and configuring your own [`IProductAssignment`](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Factory/blob/dev/src/Moryx.Orders/Assignment/Products/IProductAssignment.cs)

An example could look like the code below:

```cs
public class AutoCreateProductAssignment : ProductAssignmentBase<ProductAssignmentConfig>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override Task<IProductType> SelectProduct(Operation operation, IOperationLogger operationLogger)
    {
        var productIdentity = (ProductIdentity)operation.Product.Identity;
        var selectedType = ProductManagement.LoadType(productIdentity);
        if (selectedType == null)
        {
            selectedType = new MyProductType()
            {
                Name = operation.CreationContext.ProductName,
                Identity = new ProductIdentity(productIdentity.Identifier, productIdentity.Revision),
                // Assign any additional attributes you can derive from context
            };
            ProductManagement.SaveType(selectedType);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(selectedType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I created an implementation of `IProductManagement`, following your example. But it's not getting invoked. Do I miss something?

Comment: You probably still need to configure your new assignment in the OrderManagement config via the command center.